# Python multi-threading performance issue related to start()

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, telnet, python-multithreading

I had some performance issues with a multi-threading code to parallelize multiple telnet probes.

### Slow

My first implementation was is really slow, same a if the tasks were run sequencially:

```
for printer in printers:
    …
    thread = threading.Thread(target=collect, args=(task, printers_response), kwargs=kw)
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

### Blastlingly Fast

```
for printer in printers:
    …
    thread = threading.Thread(target=collect, args=(task, printers_response), kwargs=kw)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()  # <----- moved this

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

### Question

I don't get why moving the `start()` method change the performance so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first implementation you are actually running the code sequentially because by **calling [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) immediately after [`start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) the main thread is blocked** until the started thread is finished.

Answer (score 1):

thread.join() is blocking every thread as soon as they are created in your first implementation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [threading.Thread.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) documentation:

> Wait until the thread terminates.
>   This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates -- either normally or through an unhandled exception or until the optional timeout occurs".

In your *slow* example you start the thread and wait till it is complete, then you iterate to the next thread.

### Example

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def foo(a, b):
    while True:
        print(a + ' ' + b)
        sleep(1)

ths = []

for i in range(3):
    th = Thread(target=foo, args=('hi', str(i)))
    ths.append(th)


for th in ths:
    th.start()
    th.join()
```

#### Produces

```
hi 0
hi 0
hi 0
hi 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your slow solution you are basically not using multithreading at all. Id's running a thread, waiting to finish it and then running another - there is no difference in running everything in one thread and this solution - you are running them in series.

The second one on the other hand starts all threads and then joins them. This solution limits the execution time to the longest execution time of one single thread - you are running them in parallel.